# How can I convert django queryset list into dictionary?

Tags: django, dictionary, django-queryset

I have more then two django querysets and merged them into a list as shown output below.

```
work_queryset = Work.objects.filter(base_id = q).values('worktype', 'datestart', 'dateend', 'dailyworktime', 'remarks')
holiday_queryset = Holiday.objects.filter(base_id = q).values('holiday_type', 'datestart', 'dateend', 'remarks')
```

**Merged list**

```
merged_list = list(chain(work_queryset, holiday_queryset))
```

**output**

```
[{'datestart': u'2016-04-11', 'dateend': u'2018-07-21', 'remarks': u'Hello remarks', 'worktype': u'Remote'}, {'remarks': u'New holiday', 'datestart': u'2018-09-22', 'dateend': u'2019-09-22', 'holiday_type': u'Sick leave'}, {'remarks': u'nothing comment', 'datestart': u'2016-04-11', 'dateend': u'2016-07-20', 'holiday_type': u'Summer holiday'}]
```

**What i am trying to achieve is to convert merged_list into dictionary as shown below:**

```
[{'work' : [{'datestart': u'2016-04-11', 'dateend': u'2018-07-21', 'remarks': u'Hello remarks', 'worktype': u'Remote'}], 'holiday': [{'remarks': u'New holiday', 'datestart': u'2018-09-22', 'dateend': u'2019-09-22', 'holiday_type': u'Sick leave'}, {'remarks': u'nothing comment', 'datestart': u'2016-04-11', 'dateend': u'2016-07-20', 'holiday_type': u'Summer holiday'}]}]
```

**How can i achieve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what the out list in what you're trying to achieve is for.

Seems to me you simply want

```
{
     'work': list(work_queryset),
     'holiday': list(holiday_queryset)
}
```